# What is the "U.S. point of contact" in the ESTA application used for?

Tags: usa, esta

Last year I went to a meeting on the east coast of USA. I applied for an ESTA, and when the application form asked for a "U.S. point of contact" I put down the work address and phone number I had for the meeting organizer.

Now I'm going to the west coast for a different meeting. My ESTA is still valid, but there's no way to update the point-of-contact information.

It is **quite well known** that I don't *need* to update this information. I don't doubt this. (At least I very much hope they're not going to call the guy who organized a meeting in Boston last year if there's a problem with my entry at San Fransisco next month ...)

But I'm curious: **Why do they ask for this information in the first place**, when it will predictably be out of date for many arriving travelers? Is there any official word on what this is for?

[Note that this is a different field in the application than "address while in the U.S." which I *can* change for a subsequent trip].

Comment: @pnuts: No -- I'm curious _what they do that for_. I don't think this question discloses any _opinion_ that I could conceivably be fishing for agreement with.

Comment: @pnuts knowing the purpose of the "point of contact" question could help people to decide what answer to give.

Comment: Probably nothing more than bureaucracy, building content/history within a database. If you can't find the organizer's info, years on, you could ask the gov't to look it up for you.

Comment: @pnuts: Let me quote, then: [Constructive subjective questions inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Though actually I don't think this is a **subjective** question at all, so those lists are pretty much irrelevant no matter which of them we quote from. More to the point would be: [if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: One might ask what's the point of ESTA in the first place if it can be subverted by entering overland via Mexico. Bureaucracy, security theater, waste of taxpayers money are the likely explanations.

Comment: @JonathanReez: It seems reasonable that one point of ESTA is to make sure that some pre-checks have taken place for air arrivals, in order to reduce the number of people arriving by air that will have to be turned back. At a land border you can just refuse to let people in, and what they do when stuck on the Canadian/Mexican side of the border post is their own problem, but at an airport you need to use resources to detain them and coordinate some sort of transport away from the US.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Schengen and UK manage to do the same without preauthorization, despite a bigger number of visa-free arrivals. ESTA was implemented as a result of 9/11, so it's security theater like every other post-9/11 measure.

Comment: This seemed to me like an emergency contact. I'm not sure why they ask for that, but they ask for it on US passport applications as well. It could also be so that they can record who will be financially responsible for you or who they will contact if you stay longer than allowed.

Comment: @Rajiv: There are separate fields in the application for an "emergency contact", which I assume means a next-of-kin, possibly outside the US. Most travelers don't _have_ anyone in the US who will be financialy responsible (and certainly can't _make_ anyone financially responsible for then by an unilateral declaration).

Answer (score 5):

Presumably the same reason as on the other forms, like the [DS-160](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/ds-160-form/us-point-of-contact-information.html):

> Your U.S. Point of Contact can be any individual in the U.S. who knows
>   you and can verify, if necessary, your identity.

They also request the relationship you have, if any, to the person.

From my own assumptions, this would be to also check your reason for visiting - if your point of contact is say, a girlfriend, they might just double check your reasons for coming (are you trying to stay/work?).

Comment: Many VWP travelers won't _have_ anyone in the US who knows them and can verify their identity, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes, the link covers that case too.

Answer (score 2):

According to the ESTA [frequently asked questions](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e3s1):

> **Why is it necessary to expand the amount of ESTA information being collected from VWP travelers?**
>
> Since 9/11, the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) has evolved from a travel
>   facilitation program concerned about the threat of economic migration
>   to one with more robust security standards that are designed to
>   prevent terrorists and other criminal actors from exploiting the
>   Program.
>   ...
>   DHS must be agile and vigilant in continually adapting to evolving
>   threats and hazards. DHS has not made a significant upgrade to the
>   ESTA application in the six years that the system has been in
>   operation, despite a significant evolution in the terrorist and
>   criminal threats to the United States. DHS has determined that the
>   additional data fields to the ESTA application will enhance DHS's
>   ability to screen and more accurately and effectively identify
>   travelers who pose a potential security risk to the homeland.

So the official explanation is that it helps the US fight against terrorism. However I presume the actual explanation is the need for a [security theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_theater), rather than any valid concerns. Don't look for any real rationale as there isn't one - it's simply an example of bureaucracy collecting information for the sake of collecting it.

Comment: This does not address the particular "U.S. point of contact" item.

Comment: @HennimgMalkolm don't look for an explanation as there isn't one